# Understanding socket.io broadcasting of messages to specific users connected to a socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Using socket.io within a Node.js/Express setup, I'm trying to understand the functionality of when it comes to broadcasting messages to specific sockets/user-ids.

For example:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.join('user-1');
});
```

then further down the code, I have the following code:

```
io.to('user-1').emit('user-1 has joined the room');
```

What I am trying to understand is the broadcasting of messages to specific users.

Say I I had 5 different users accessing the website that has the above code and assuming that each of these users had their own unique user-ids,

i.e. user-1, user-2, user-3 etc, which was passed in as part of the `socket.join('user-2')` for user-2, `socket.join('user-3')` for user-3 and so on.

Now if I wanted to broadcast a message from a specific endpoint to a specific user, say user-3 ONLY, could I achieve this with just the following code:

```
io.to('user-3').emit('user-3 has joined the room');
```

or would I also need to associate each user connected with the socket#id?

I'm hoping the io.to(....).emit(....) syntax can use the user-id alone but if not, what would be the best approach to accomplish the above as there may well be a lot of users connected.

Comment: Have you checked the rooms and namespace concepts in socket.io ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle Just had a look at rooms and namespaces concepts in socket.io and looks like this is what I am after. Firstly, it seems I can use the rooms `io.to('some room').emit('some event');` concept by replacing `some room` with my `io.to('user-#').emit('some event');` so thanks for that. My only question is, can I just use rooms concept without namespace?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle - I assume so.